# split the node elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html text as follows:

```
  <p>
     Sample <span style="font-weight:bold"> code .... [upto 100 characters]</span>
     <i>italic content</i>
  </p>
```

I want to output as

```
  <p>
     Sample <span style="font-weight:bold"> code .... [upto 80 characters]</span>
  </p>
  <p>
     <span style="font-weight:bold">
         [remaining 20 characters]
     </span>
     <i>italic content</i>
  </p>
```

As i need to show only 90 text characters. sometimes I get  elements in the content,so i need to break the node elements exactly and render properly.

Please can any one help me how to do it using jquery.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And the question is, what have you tried...

Comment: i dont know how to proceed first :( as i dont have idea how to split elements

Comment: well, first maybe try to learn some javascript :) that would be good step forward.

Comment: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com) & [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('p').each(function () {
    var $span = $(this).children('span');
    var text = $span.text();
    $span.text(text.substring(0, 80));
    if (text.length > 80) {
        $('<p />').append($('<span />', {
            text: text.substring(80),
            style: 'font-weight:bold'
        })).append($(this).find('i')).insertAfter(this)
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Kgh7M/)

Answer (score 0):

Add element ids to the sample code & run-off spans, style them with css

```
 <style>
    #sample-code { font-weight: bold };
    #run-off {font-weight: bold };
 </style>

 <p>
     Sample <span id="sample-code"> code .... [upto 80 characters]</span>
 </p>
 <p>
    <span id="run-off">
     [remaining 20 characters]
    </span>
    <i>italic content</i>
 </p>
```

then when the document loads process it

```
 $(function(){
    var text = $("#sample-code").text();
    // should probably ensure the length is greater than 80 chars
    var sample = text.substr(0, 80);
    var runoff = text.substr(81);

    $("#sample-code").text(sample);
    $("#run-off").text(runoff);
 });
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WqvtC/1/)

Comment: I dont get id,this is the text where i take from tiny mce so I have html code. So i have to generate dynamically by separating node elements

Comment: add the id so you have something to select against, instead of enumerating through the entire DOM.  your question didn't say anything about tiny mce...

Comment: because i thought everyone might understand my question but i didnt recognize people will understand in different way,sorry I dont get id,I will take only the content of the tiny mce,that is my requirement.I will get huge data,i gave sample code

Comment: What's to get?  Just add ids to the elements containg code, so you don't have to enumerate the entire page DOM.  You simply select the elements you need.  You can choose to style them or not.

Comment: do you have any idea on tinymce?I dont go and edit the content using html code and enter id for each span,it doesnt work for me like that

Comment: Do you have idea of columnizer plugin,where he will break node elements,rather what ever elements come through,he doesnt make it specific

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going for the look, try span#sample-code { max-width: whatever look nice px; }